# Move the current word left or right ("leapfrogging" other words)

Tags: vim

I'd like to move the word under the cursor and move it to the left or the right ("leapfrogging" other words). For example, if we had this sentence:

The quick fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.

I would like to set my cursor on "brown", press some key combination and move it between "quick" and "fox". This would be similar to moving lines up and down ([e or ]e), but for words to go left or right.

Comment: Good question. One you thing you should know, however, is that most questions we ask about Vim can actually be solved using mapping, just like @Habi's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move word under cursor one word to right:

```
nmap <F10> dawelpb
```

Move word under cursor one word to left:

```
nmap <F9> dawbPb
```

Both do not work very well for words followed by punctuation marks. If you want to move a word with that special characters, use the following mappings:

Move right:

```
nmap <F10> dawElpB
```

Move left:

```
nmap <F9> dawBPB
```

[Edit]: Explanations added:

Explanation 'dawElpB': 'daw' deletes the word under the cursor, 'E' places cursor at the end of the word right to the cursor, 'l' moves the cursor one position to the right, 'p' pasts the word and 'B' places the cursor at the beginning of the pasted word.

Explanation 'dawBPB': 'daw' deletes the word under the cursor, 'B' places cursor at the beginning of the word left to the cursor, 'P' pasts the word and 'B' places the cursor at the beginning of the pasted word.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I should have thought about the steps that I could take for this work. I am still learning how to harness this new-found power :).

Answer (score 1):

```
daw5bhp
```

Explanation:

daw: delete around word (cursor can be anywhere inside "brown")

5b: go back 5 words

hp: move the cursor to the left one space then paste

Answer (score 1):

I have these mappings in my .vimrc:

```
" pushes current line up & down
nnoremap <leader><Up> ddkP
nnoremap <leader><Down> ddp

" pushes word under the cursor to the left & to the right
nnoremap <leader><Left> "_yiw?\w\+\_W\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>
nnoremap <leader><Right> "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o>/\w\+\_W\+<CR><C-l>
```

It's waaay more complex than @Habi's answer — which I'm going to try — but it works very well.

I found it on the [Vim wiki.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines)

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a solution to the question on [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines).
However, over the years I've moved away from it as it changes various registers like `@/`, which impacts the highlighted search pattern (when `hlsearch` is set).

Now, I'm using [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/vim-tip-swap-word.vim).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the plugin, as well!